# Como puedo usar un input sin la etiqueta form?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Necesito convertir el valor de un input a una variable php, normalmente se haría con un formulario de tipo post y que el input tenga un name, pero el problema es que ese form lo envío a la misma página, por ello necesito capturar el valor del input sin que se use un formulario, gracias, se puede hacer con php, javascript o algo?, gracias

Comment: Conozco una manera de hacerlo en Javascript

Comment: Por cierto tu pregunta está muy mal planteada, deberías de leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: Busca sobre llamadas AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes hacer con javascript solo le agregas un id a tu input ej:

```
// esto en el html
<input type="text" id="dato" name="dato" />


// esto en el código javascript
let dato = document.getElementById("dato").value;
 console.log(dato);
```

Comment: No se evidencia explicacion alguna de lo que hace el codigo, esta bien que desees ayudar, pero como eres usuario nuevo amablemente te pido que revises porfavor [answer], pues el manual del sitio es muy claro, donde se especifica que dudas que no sean claras, que esten basadas en opiniones o que no contengan un ejemplo minimo y verificable (codigo), simplemente no deben responderse, la pregunta que hizo el usuario tiene estos 3 problemas juntos, por ende hay que abstenerse de responder.

Answer (score 0):

Para ello puedes usar vanilla JavaScript de forma muy sencilla

Solo debemos tomar el valor que escribe el usuario en el campo y almacenarlo en una variable y despues con ella puedes hacer lo que gustes. En el enlace tienes un ejemplo corriendo:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/luis-alfredo-serrano-d-az/pen/gOPgQgJ)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="text" name="user" id="user" oninput="test()">
    </div>
    <h1 id="title"></h1>
    <script>
        function test() {
            let a;
            a = document.getElementById('user').value;
            document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = a;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Aunque tu pregunta no está muy clara, si lo que deseas es enviar información a Backend te aconsejo que al hacerlo uses el metodo post ya sea por formularios HTML, o con AJAX o Vuex

Comment: Ya eres un poco mas antiguo recuerda que NO se responde a este tipo de preguntas, porfavor leer [answer].

Comment: A ver si puedes ser más especifico en informarme que no estoy contestando de forma adecuada...

Comment: Estas contestando una pregunta que no debe ser contestada debido a la forma en la que la planteo el usuario, tecnicamente no es que la estes respondiendo mal. Solo que este tipo de preguntas mal hechas no deben ser respondidas, el manual especifica mejor el porque: [answer].

Comment: Tienes razón, le falta contenido a la pregunta y no debió ser  contestada.